# Parent DIV retain size when transforming child img

Tags: html, css, overflow, transform

The original size of the image or the parent Div have not be set with specific number as I want to use various images.

The goal is a zoom effect when hovering. The thing is that while the image is transforming (zoom) then the container div is taking the new size. So how can I retain the size and also apply an overflow:hidden so that the image will zoom within the initial size of the parent div?

**HTML**

```
<div class="time-line-box">
    <div class="imgmask">
        <img src="images/someimage.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

    <p>some text some text some text </p>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.imgmask img{
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
    transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.37, 0.23, 0.34, 0.99) 0s, opacity 0.22s ease-out 0s;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden
}
.imgmask{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.imgmask:hover img{
    opacity: 0.95;
    transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1.2) !important;
    transition: transform 2.2s cubic-bezier(0.37, 0.23, 0.34, 0.99) 0s, opacity 0.22s ease-out 0s;
}
```

Comment: What is restricting you to set a size of parent div?

Comment: Well there is "bigger" parent div which takes 50% of the screen which is the max size for the child divs and therefore for the image. The thing is that I want to use various heights of the images. So that's why I can't set a specific height. The width even though it's not clear from my code has been set from the bigger parent.

Comment: Can you not set the overflow hidden to parent container ? And what problem is it if the `div` containing image is also resized?

Comment: As you can see in the code the parent div is the imgmask and there is already a overflow:hidden. But it doesn't work since it is taking the image's size. I want it to retain it's initial size despite the fact that the img will change the size on hovering.

Comment: What initial size you want to retain? If your div does not have a size set. then there is nothing like initial at all.

Comment: I know this. The div's initial size is the child image's initial size. If the image will change its size I want the div to not change its size. So how can I work around this?

Comment: Do you have liberty to use JS ?

Comment: ............yes

Comment: You can set the size of each parent `div` based on the image size it holds. This way each div will be of different size. You must and should have size set to the div to get that effect.

Comment: A transform is purely visual it's does not affect parent size at all. I can't see how a `scale` would affect it.

Comment: @Paulie_D In your code it did though. Didn't you see that it got the image's size? Even with overflow-hidden set it didn't work.

Comment: Let us know if you find a solution. @Mdermez Other than suggested below.

Comment: The image holder is NOT getting larger...if it did the text would move..and it doesn't.

Comment: Calm down :) I found the solution

Answer (score 1):

Change the image `width:100%` to `max-width:100%;`

```css
.imgmask img {
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
  transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.37, 0.23, 0.34, 0.99) 0s, opacity 0.22s ease-out 0s;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden
}

.imgmask {
  overflow: hidden;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.imgmask:hover img {
  opacity: 0.95;
  transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1.2) !important;
  transition: transform 2.2s cubic-bezier(0.37, 0.23, 0.34, 0.99) 0s, opacity 0.22s ease-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="time-line-box">
  <div class="imgmask">
    <img src="http://www.placebacon.net/400/300" alt="">
  </div>

  <p>some text some text some text </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Well there is "bigger" parent div which takes 50% of the screen which is the max width for the child divs and therefore for the image. The thing is that I want to use various heights of the images. So that's why I can't set a specific height. The width even though it's not clear from my code has been set from the bigger parent. So in your code even if I set up max-width and max-height as you can see it takes its child's size. So it's not working .

Comment: Then you need to specify the **actual** problem in your code.

Comment: Both case can be the problem. In your provided code even if my problem was the width it doesn't solve anything as you can see if you run the code. It takes the childs size which is what I don't want and this is described in my brief.

Answer (score 1):

You must set the size of your `div` container.

Once the page is loaded, run a similar logic in a loop for all images.

```
function resize() {
    $('.parent-div').css({
        width: $(this).children('.child-img').width(),
        height: $(this).children('.child-img').height(),
    });
}
```

Considering this is your HTML.

```
<div class="time-line-box">
    <div class="imgmask parent-div">
        <img src="images/someimage.jpg" alt="" class="child-img">
    </div>
    <p>some text some text some text </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was a tricky thing that eliminated the empty space beneath each image thus not allowing to extend further when transforming. I also changed the display of the image. This is not a general answer for this thread I am just stating what worked for me.

Here's an "upvote" for your answers. Thanks for helping

```
.imgmask img{
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
    transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.37, 0.23, 0.34, 0.99) 0s, opacity 0.22s ease-out 0s;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

And deleted any margins that occurred from other parts of my code.